Which libc/stdio IO functions Perl uses to open a file?
Which libc/stdio functions does Perl use to open and read a file (e.g. for perl -e 'open(F,"<","test.txt");print(<F>);')?
I tried running this command under strace and it gave me a sequence open -> fcntl -> ioctl -> lseek -> fstat -> mmap -> read. strace intercepts syscalls, so I'm wondering what are the higher-level libc/stdio functions are actually being called in https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/perlio.c and https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/doio.c? The Perl I/O codebase has many layers of indirection, so I'm struggling to understand it.
I'm not a Perl pro, so not understanding https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO and the codebase sufficiently enough :(
Thanks!

Why does this matter? How does it affect how you use Perl?

If you search the codebase for fopen you'll find a number of references. It looks like it has its own I/O abstraction layer, and how it uses stdio seems to be OS-dependent.

E.g. README.solaris mentions "perl calls open() and
then fdopen(3C) with the resulting file descriptor"

Depends on the layer.
There are two options for the base layer of ordinary handles: :unix and :stdio.

The :unix layer is is defined in perlio.c as PerlIO_unix.

For opening, :unix uses PerlIOUnix_open, which calls PerlLIO_open3_cloexec, which calls PerlLIO_open3, which is defined as open (except maybe on MVS).

For writing, :unix uses PerlIOUnix_write, which calls PerlLIO_write, which is defined as write.



The :stdio layer is is defined in perlio.c as PerlIO_stdio.

For opening, :stdio uses PerlIOStdio_open. Follow from there.

For writing, :stdio uses PerlIOStdio_write, which calls PerlSIO_fwrite, which is defined as fwrite.




The selection of the base layer appears to be:

If a layer is provided to open, use that one.
If a process-wide default is provided (e.g. using the PERLIO env var), use that one.
Otherwise, use the default selected when Perl was built. This can apparently be :stdio in some circumstances, but it's usually :perlio, and :perlio adds an underlying :unix layer.

Note that :unix is used on Windows as well. It refers to the libc functions rather than anything specific to Unix.
[All links for v5.40.0.]

it also appears that Perl needs fstat to work

Ah, you want all the system calls? Well, I identified the functions to look at.

yeah, I'm interested in all libc functions / syscalls used by Perl on a typical file reading code path. thanks for referencing the relevant functions in the Perl codebase. Ha-ha I'll also have a similar question for system(...) function and backticks: where to find it in the Perl's code tree? and whether it uses popen or some manual fork / exec. Basically would like to intercept some external command invokations and handle them in-process and do without any forks/process spawns...

Search for pp_system. It'll be in one of the pp*.c files. I believe some of this is OS-specific. See $os/* for OS-specific code.
